# Unity 3D Particle System Snow effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, particle-system

Within unity 3D, Im building a 2d runner within which I have created a particle system that emits snow like particles from a single location at the top right corner of the main camera off screen.

I attached the particle emitter to the main camera so theres always snow like particles on screen, however, as the speed of the main camera increases, so does the speed of the particle emitter, which eventually starts emitting particles off screen.

How can I change the settings of the emitter so that the speed of the emitter does not affect the direction of the particles. Lastly for more details, I have set the shape of the emitter to be a cone, and the simulation space to be world. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **Simulation Space** setting of your *ParticleSystem* component : [Particle System main module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysMainModule.html).

**EDIT**
Since I didn't noticed at first you wanted the particles speed to increase with the *Camera* accelerating (my bad...) here's a way you could fake the effect :

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Attributes
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_MaxTransformSpeed;

    [SerializeField]
    private float m_MinStartSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_MaxStartSpeed;

    private ParticleSystem m_Particles;
    private Vector3 m_PreviousPosition;
    #endregion

    #region MonoBehaviour
    protected void Start()
    {
        m_Particles = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    protected void Update()
    {
        Vector3 cameraSpeed = transform.position - m_PreviousPosition;
        m_Particles.startSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(m_MinStartSpeed + (m_MaxStartSpeed - m_MinStartSpeed) * cameraSpeed.magnitude / m_MaxTransformSpeed, m_MinStartSpeed, m_MaxStartSpeed);
        m_PreviousPosition = transform.position;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Instead of being based on only the latest frame you can either save *N* older positions and get the average speed value of *N* deltas or directly send the script the amount of movement you apply to your *Camera* if you move it manually.

Comment: I have changed the Simulation Space to be World already, all that does is not cause the particles to always move in the camera. My problem is that as the movement speed of the emitter increases, the particles start getting affected by the speed and get emitted towards the top of the camera in a stream from the top right of the screen to the top left of the screen. When the emitter is not moving, it looks like snow. falling from the top right of the screen to the bottom. I want to simulate that behaviour even when the camera is moving.

Comment: @pretzo246 I just tried with an empty scene, a moving _Camera_ and a "snow" _ParticleSystem_ as child of the camera : it works as intended. [Here](http://i.giphy.com/l0HlMstNcGK2bCFri.gif)'s the result with _World_ setting for the **Simulation Space** property and [here](http://i.giphy.com/3oz8xP1je4r78JsCOs.gif)'s with _Local_.

Comment: I feel like the Local setting was better suited within that scenario, as with the World setting, you saw how the particles slowly started appearing off screen when the speed of the emitter increased? What I want is for the particles to keep being generated on screen and not slowly start being generated off screen.

Comment: Ok my bad I didn't get it at first that you wanted the snow to actually move faster over time : I'll edit my answer to help you on this :)